# MotionLayout ReyclerView Visiblity Issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I have a Constraint Layout which contains a RecyclerView, a TextInputEditText and a LottieAnimationView.

It works as such:

- On startup, only the LottieAnimation is visible until my LiveData fetches data from repo and updates successfully.
- After data is fetched, the LottieView is hidden and the RecyclerView and TextInputEditText becomes visible

Now i want that when i scroll my RecyclerView, the TextInputEditText also scrolls.

I made use of MotionLayout. Except it is not working properly. After the LiveData is updated, my LottieAnimation becomes invisible successfully, but only the TextInputEditText becomes visible. My RecyclerView list doesn't appear.

fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="ViewModel"
            type="...AllServicesViewModel" />

        <import type="android.view.View" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/Root_All_Services"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_all_services_header">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/TextField_Search"
            style="@style/Mes.TextField.Search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:drawablePadding="-24dp"
            android:hint="@string/action_search"
            android:text="@={ViewModel.searchQuery}"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:padding="24dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView_Services"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/TextField_Search" />

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/Anim_Loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/raw_anim_loading_services" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>

</layout>
```

scene_all_services_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:onTouchUp="stop"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/TextField_Search" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/TextField_Search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ConstraintOverride
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView_Services"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/Anim_Loading"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/Illus_Error"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/TextField_Search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ConstraintOverride
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView_Services"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/Anim_Loading"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/Illus_Error"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore" />

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Can someone please help me out ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing your <ConstraintOverride /> tag for your RecyclerView_Services  with a regular <Constraint /> tag with motion:visibilityMode="ignore"?

Comment: Constraint  android:id="@+id/Anim_Loading"  motion:visibilityMode="ignore" /> are removing all the constraints from the views Anim_Loading & Illus_Error, Use ConstraintOverride or add all the constraints for those view.

But I don't think that is your main problem. Try simplifying till you isolate the problem.
Try a few experiments:
,Set RecyclerView to fix height.  
,Try adding layoutDuringTransition="honorRequest"
,Look at UI in Layout Inspector

Comment: should i use only <Constraint> tags ?

Comment: With <Constraint id.., attr..., attr... > you must provide all the ConstraintSet attributes as if from scratch as the base constraint and transform attributes are erased
With <ConstraintOverrid id..., attr...,> You only need provide the the changes.
Ether approach is valid.
It might be simpler to think about <Constraint ..> because you know what ever you see there is all that applies.